# 012 upgrade - cidrsubnet w/ module call

Tags: terraform

After 0.12 upgrade of terraform, I can no longer call cidrhost on a custom module.

The complaint is that "prefix" must be of type string.

Just trying to modify via cidrhost the 0 index element from a custom module, which is fairly straight forward.

Have tried 'tostring' and various other manipulations but still no resolution.

```
module "network1_subnets" {
  inside_subnets      = ["1"]
  inside_subnets_name = ["Networking1"]
  source              = "./inside_subnets"
  vpc_cidr            = aws_vpc.main.cidr_block
  vpc_id              = aws_vpc.main.id
  dc_name             = var.DC_NAME
}

resource "aws_subnet" "inside_subnets-a" {
  count             = length(var.inside_subnets)
  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]
  cidr_block = cidrsubnet(
    cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 8, element(var.inside_subnets, count.index)),
    1,
    0,
  )
  #tags = {
  #  Name = ${lower(var.dc_name)}-${element(var.inside_subnets_name, 
count.index)}-pri
  #}
}

data "template_file" "prdfwl00_init" {
  template = file("prdfwl00-config.tpl")
  vars = {
    network1          = cidrhost(element(module.network1_subnets.subnets- 
a, 0), 4)
  }
}
```

Error:

> ```
> Invalid function argument
>
>   on firewall_launch.tf line 5, in data "template_file" "prdfwl00_init":
>    5:     network1          = cidrhost(element(module.network1_subnets.subnets-a, 0), 4)
>     |----------------
>     | module.network1_subnets.subnets-a is tuple with 1 element
>
> Invalid value for "prefix" parameter: string required.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with the `subnets-a` output rather than with your `cidrhost` call. Specifically, the module seems to be a list of lists instead of a list of strings.

You didn't include the definition of `output "subnets-a"` in the question here, but my guess would be that if you look at the definition you will find that it contains something like this:

```
output "subnets-a" {
  value = [some-other-expression]
}
```

If so, you can remove the brackets to avoid creating a one-element list, and instead just return your `some-other-expression` (whatever it actually is) instead:

```
output "subnets-a" {
  value = some-other-expression
}
```

As long as your real expression produces a list of strings, you should then get the result you were looking for.

There's more information on this problem in the Upgrade Guide section [Referring to List Variables](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html#referring-to-list-variables).

Comment: Interesting - I had not though about the outputs. Indeed I was outputting to a list which is needed to later retrieve those values.


    output "subnets-a" {
      value = [
        aws_subnet.inside_subnets-a.*.cidr_block,
      ]
    }

Comment: flatten() as indicated in the document (which I reviewed but missed) was the correct answer here.